# Using RegEx to extract First Names and Ranks in Python

Tags: python, regex, database

I am attempting to extract the following information from a data base:

- Year (once)
- First names
- Rank

The tricky part is ignoring certain parts while extracting others.

The database I am trying to pull from appears in this format:

```
Popularity in 2018
Rank    Male name   Number of males     Female name     Number of females
1       Liam        19,837              Emma            18,688
2       Noah        18,267              Olivia          17,921
3       William     14,516              Ava             14,924
4       James       13,525              Isabella        14,464
5       Oliver      13,389              Sophia          13,928
6       Benjamin    13,381              Charlotte       12,940
7       Elijah      12,886              Mia             12,642
8       Lucas       12,585              Amelia          12,301
9       Mason       12,435              Harper          10,582
10      Logan       12,352              Evelyn          10,376
```

```
import re

year = r'\d{4}'
name = r'[A-Z][a-z].*$'
rank = r'\d{1,3}'

def extract_names(f):
    match_x = re.search(year, f)
    match_y = re.search(name, f)
    match_z = re.search(rank, f)
    x = match_x.group()
    y = match_y.groups()
    z = match_z.groups()

    def print_match(x, y=False, z=False):
        if match_y and match_z:
            print(x, y, z)
        elif match_y:
            print(x, y, 'is unranked')
        else:
            print("No match found for year", x)

    print_match(x, y, z + ".")
```

I'm getting a few different errors with a few different codes, but what I want to pull is a dictionary (named by year) and then the first name, with a rank

The idea is to pull the information in a way that I can call one name, say "Liam", and it gives an over-all trend through the years of the popularity of the name Liam.

Help! :)

Comment: One of the errors I am running into is that I am having issues w/ differentiating between the words "Male" and "Female" and actual names w/ RegEx.

Comment: Differentiate those from actual names is not the strength of regex. It's easier to just ignore the 2nd row since the column names should be pretty standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by a simple REGEX `r'(\d{4})|(?<=\n)(\d+)\s+(\w+)'`:

```
import re

text ="""
Popularity in 2018
Rank    Male name   Number of males     Female name     Number of females
1       Liam        19,837              Emma            18,688
2       Noah        18,267              Olivia          17,921
3       William     14,516              Ava             14,924
4       James       13,525              Isabella        14,464
5       Oliver      13,389              Sophia          13,928
6       Benjamin    13,381              Charlotte       12,940
7       Elijah      12,886              Mia             12,642
8       Lucas       12,585              Amelia          12,301
9       Mason       12,435              Harper          10,582
10      Logan       12,352              Evelyn          10,376
""".strip()
year = '(\d{4})'
rank_name = '(?<=\n)(\d+)\s+(\w+)'
pattern = r'{}|{}'.format(year, rank_name)
for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):
    year, rank, name = match.groups()
    if year:
        print('Year is: ', year)
    else:
        print('Name {} RANK: {}'.format(name, rank))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Year is:  2018
Name Liam RANK: 1
Name Noah RANK: 2
Name William RANK: 3
Name James RANK: 4
Name Oliver RANK: 5
Name Benjamin RANK: 6
Name Elijah RANK: 7
Name Lucas RANK: 8
Name Mason RANK: 9
Name Logan RANK: 10
```

Here every match have 3 groups, contains either year or name and rank.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you need regex since the data is fairly regular. Loop through the lines may work.

```
db = '''Popularity in 2018
Rank    Male name   Number of males     Female name     Number of females
1       Liam        19,837              Emma            18,688
2       Noah        18,267              Olivia          17,921
3       William     14,516              Ava             14,924
4       James       13,525              Isabella        14,464
5       Oliver      13,389              Sophia          13,928
6       Benjamin    13,381              Charlotte       12,940
7       Elijah      12,886              Mia             12,642
8       Lucas       12,585              Amelia          12,301
9       Mason       12,435              Harper          10,582
10      Logan       12,352              Evelyn          10,376 '''
```

```
lines = db.split('\n')
year = lines[0].split(' ')[-1]
for line in lines[2:]:
    data = list(filter(None, line.split(' ')))
    rank, male, female = data[0], data[1], data[3]
```

I think the spacing between columns are actually tabs, so it's even easier and you can simply split by `\t`.

After this, you can save the information however you want.